# Нужно получить @src из iframe используя xpath

Tags: python, html, парсер, iframe, xpath

Есть [страница](http://vkino.ua/ru/show/beguschii-v-labirinte-ispitanie-ognem-maze-runner-the-scorch-trials#)

На странице есть ролик с Ютуба в iframe.

```html
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vvKYhcUSrY4?autoplay=0&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fvkino.ua"></iframe>
```

Помогите получить линк на ролик из `src`?

Хром при копировании Xpath выдает `//*[@id="player"]` и все. Как я не крутился, не получается. В качестве инструмента использую lxml (python).

Comment: //*[@id="player"]/@src

Comment: @splash58 Пробовал. Еще пробовал для проверки print(tree.xpath('name(//*[@id="trailer-holder"]/*[1])')) и в результате получаю не iframe, а div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все очень просто. Кстати, для `html` страниц лучше не использовать парсер `xml` – у `html` допускаются ошибки в структуре, из-за чего `xml` парсер может не захотеть парсить.

Для `lxml` есть простое решение нужно импортировать не `from lxml import etree`, а `from lxml.html import etree`:

```py
text = """
<html><body>
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vvKYhcUSrY4?autoplay=0&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fvkino.ua"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
"""

from lxml.html import etree

root = etree.fromstring(text)

# Ищем в любом месте документа атрибут 'src', который принадлежит
# тегу 'iframe' с атрибутом 'id' равным 'player':
match = root.xpath('//iframe[@id="player"]/@src')
if match:
    print(match[0])

# Ищем в любом месте документа атрибут 'src', который принадлежит
# любому тегу с атрибутом 'id' равным 'player':
match = root.xpath('//*[@id="player"]/@src')
if match:
    print(match[0])

# Ищем в любом месте документа тег 'iframe' с атрибутом 'id' 
# равным 'player':
match = root.xpath('//iframe[@id="player"]')
if match:
    print(match[0].attrib['src'])
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/vvKYhcUSrY4?autoplay=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=1&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fvkino.ua
https://www.youtube.com/embed/vvKYhcUSrY4?autoplay=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=1&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fvkino.ua
https://www.youtube.com/embed/vvKYhcUSrY4?autoplay=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=1&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fvkino.ua
```